# Error in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel 5.2 and encountered a problem in my code:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate; 
...
if(Gate::denies('add-article'))
   {
      return redirect()->back()->with(['message'=>'Unregistered user']);
   }
```

After I got an error:

```
 Non-static method Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate::allows() cannot be called statically
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Did you try initiating an object of _Gate_ and start using its _denies()_ method?

Answer (score 3):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
// or
use Gate;
```

You want the Facade, not the underlying class of the Facade. The Facade is a static proxy for an instance of that class.

If you want to use the class, `Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate`, directly you would need an instance of it.

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Authorization - Checking Abilities - via the Gate Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization#via-the-gate-facade)

[Laravel 5.2 Docs - Facades - Class Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades#facade-class-reference)